# Google Maps zoom out to GPS and markers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-maps

I am trying to show three things on map :
GPS (the current location) , Marker 1 , Marker 2, but I am not sure I am doing it right or not ! Here is my code :

```
 self.startMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.startLatitude, longitude: self.startLongitude)
 self.startMarker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pin Start")
 self.startMarker.map = self.mapView


 self.endMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.endLatitude, longitude: self.endLongitude)
 self.endMarker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pin End")
 self.endMarker.map = self.mapView


 let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.startLatitude,self.startLongitude)
 let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.endLatitude,self.endLongitude)
 let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
 let camera = self.mapView.camera(for: bounds, insets:.zero)
 self.mapView.camera = camera!
```

More Code :

```
  // MARK: - Google Map

private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse {
                mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            }
          }
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let newLocation = locations.last
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newLocation!.coordinate, zoom: 14)
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
```

The result is like this :

[image: it show only the start pin]

What I need :

[image]

**EDITED**

```
if let myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation {

let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(myLocation.coordinate)
path.add(self.startMarker.position)
path.add(self.endMarker.position)

let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
                                        self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 40))
```

}

Comment: I have added an answer check it out, make sure *didUpdateLocations()* is called.

Answer (score 12):

**Showing All Markers with screen bound:**

Here I am trying to provide you one simple example, hope this will help you.
Using this, you can show any number of markers on screen.

**Example:**

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
for var i in 0 ..< array.count //Here take your "array" which contains lat and long.
{
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    let lat = Double(array.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey(lattitude) as! String)
    let long = Double(arrayr.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey(longitude) as! String)      
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!,long!)
    path.addCoordinate(marker.position)
    marker.map = self.mapView
}
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
self.mapView!.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 30.0))
```

Comment: would you please tell me how should I fill `array.count` ?

Comment: @Mc.Lover See, if you have various lat & long and if your getting it from backend then you can use that one directly or else create your own array by adding your lat longs and use that array.

Comment: Thank you ! but still doesn't work ! would you please check out my edited code ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below code, this is converted from ObjC code here is the documentation of [`includingCoordinate`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds.html#a63cffdf310ca19c6bab74c9a4034aadd)

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
bounds.includingCoordinate(self.startMarker.position)
bounds.includingCoordinate(self.endMarker.position)
bounds.includingCoordinate(yourCurrentLocationPosition)
self.mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate(fitBounds:bounds, padding:20.0f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    showMarkers(locations)
    //stop updating location when you find suitable
}

func showMarkers(userLocation: [CLLocation]){

    let location1: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.startLatitude, longitude: self.startLongitude)
    let location2: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.endLatitude, longitude: self.endLongitude)
    let location3: CLLocationCoordinate2D = userLocation[0].coordinate

    var locationArray = []
    locationArray.append(location1)
    locationArray.append(location2)
    locationArray.append(location3)

    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for location in locationArray
    {
        let latitude = location.valueForKey("latitude")
        let longitude = location.valueForKey("longitude")

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        marker.map = self.mapView
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 100)
    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(update)
}
```

**Note:**

`locationArray` contains three locations ie. *Marker 1*, *Marker 2*, *user location*.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is looking for solution with Objective-C, This might help

```
//Locations
CLLocationCoordinate2D source = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.2880, 72.1587);
CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.1780, 72.9577);
CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.0760, 72.8777);

//Create a GMSMutablePath
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath new];
[path addCoordinate:source];
[path addCoordinate:userLocation];
[path addCoordinate:destination];

//Create bounds
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];

//Update the camera position
[mapview animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds]];
```